# MEW does not recognize Veri as ERC-20

Tags: erc-20

Attempting to integrate my Veri into MEW, I get response that this is not ERC-20 token. I purchased on EtherDelta & my Veri still shows up there (my MEW wallet being serviced through MetaMask).

Does log-in make a difference? I'm using Private Key, do I need to log in using JSON?

Any guidance appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

VERI is already added as default token. Please check your address on ethplorer.io and let me know if your VERI balance shows there.

Comment: No, it does not. It shows up on EtherDelta (where my MEW is imported using MetaMask) - as being IN my MEW already. 
I do have a transaction log. I know that some of my transactions failed due to insufficient gas. 
Thank you, I so much appreciate your help